# Directly Control USB Output?? (any language)

Tags: usb

So I know that for a USB port type A there is 2 ouputs/inputs. I'm working on a simple electronic circuit and I would like to ouput datas on to my computer so a program could work with it. How (without it getting too complicated on the circuit side) can I just choose the output of the USB port and read the input just on the on/off level?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USB is more complicated than what you are describing. It sounds like what you really want is a serial port, where you can use the TX and RX lines as your output and input to the PC, or manually control the modem control or GPIO pins. You can still do this with USB via a [USB to UART Bridge device](https://www.google.com/search?q=usb%20to%20uart%20bridge&oq=USB%20to%20UART%20BRidge&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60l2j0l3.2816j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8).

If you are simply looking to toggle an I/O pin, some of these devices also have general purpose I/O pins for this type of thing. You can set it to low/high from the PC if it is set to be an output and read the I/O value if it is an input.

You can talk to it as a serial device from your computer using normal serial communications such as [POSIX method for Linux or OSX](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html) or the [Commuincations API for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff802693.aspx). In this case you can also set the flow control to manual and use the RTS/CTS pins as GPIOs.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the www.Nusbio.net device.

it is an USB device that give any .NET programming languages access to 8 gpios and also SPI and I2c bus.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly control the USB inputs and outputs like you want to do.  However, there are various solutions that involve connecting a USB device to your computer and sending commands to it that use its inputs and outputs.  One such solution is called [Firmata](http://firmata.org/).